# What to do when someone provides support money?

Tags: finance, nonprofit

I run a nonprofit project and someone supports me with money.  Beside thanking them, what else I can do?

Should I publicly thank them, so that (1) they are proud, and (2) others will be motivated?

If yes, what should I do to avoid making anybody offended?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, *ask* them if they want to be thanked in public. Some people just prefer to stay out of the spotlights.

And it should indeed be balanced with the attention your other volunteers get; they contribute time, which can be even more valuable than money. You can thank them all together, or make some kind of recurring article in your website/newsletter where one volunteer writes/tells something about themselves (other hobbies, their work, or their specific tasks in your organization – some of them might want to stay anonymous) and passes it on to the next one.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by making a recurring item to pass on to the next one. Can you give an example?

Comment: I hope my edit makes it clear. If not, I will try to find some examples, but I'm not sure if many can be found online (I've seen them mostly in paper newsletters...)

Comment: so it seems to me that thanking volunteers are much better than thanking donors (unless the donors are organizations?)

Answer (score 0):

Depends a lot on your nonprofit's structure.

There are various types of supports one might give depending on time frame between support, if it is one-time or recurring,...

One may use [Patreon](https://www.patreon.com) for inspiration on various levels of payment and their associated accesses/benefits. These levels will help you treat each supporter the same way.

That being said, I would first of all clarify the overall support structure and the various types of support people might give. That way you'll make sure no-one gets upset for being treated differently.  This might also help get more people involved, depending on the benefits one might get from supporting your project and what one seeks.